# Region of attraction of simple ODE with perturbation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory, basins-of-attraction

There are a few nice discussions about ROA  covering a few subtopics:

1. [Region of attraction of : $x'=-y-x^3,y'=x-y^3$ via Lyapunov Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529824/region-of-attraction-of-x-y-x3-y-x-y3-via-lyapunov-function)
2. [Region of attraction and stability via liapunov's function (No2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617765/region-of-attraction-and-stability-via-liapunovs-function-no2)
3. [Basin of attractions with continuity and discontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495784/basin-of-attractions-with-continuity-and-discontinuity)
4. [Strength of attraction of fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388219/strength-of-attraction-of-fixed-points)
5. [Can the basin of attraction be multiple intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186866/can-the-basin-of-attraction-be-multiple-intervals)

Now, consider the following simplest example:

$$\dot{x} = x(x-1)(x+1)$$ $[-1,1]$ is the ROA.

Now consider the two dimensional case:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\dot{x} = x(x-1)(x+1)\\
&\dot{y} = y(y-1)(y+1)
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}Obviously, ROA is a square. However, if I consider the following coupled ODE:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\dot{x} = x(x-1)(x+1) + \epsilon (y-x)\\
&\dot{y} = y(y-1)(y+1) + \epsilon (x-y)
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation} where $\epsilon$ is a very small number. Or

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\dot{x} = x(x-1)(x+1) + \epsilon (-y+x)\\
&\dot{y} = y(y-1)(y+1) + \epsilon (-x+y)
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation} Then I have the following ROAs:  (blue line-case three, black line-case two, red line-case one)

[image]

> My questions are:

1. > There are two different tilt directions for case two and three. I know this is because of the slope of the coupling term (for case two, the slope of $x$ and $y$ in the coupling terms are $-1$). But how could I analyze this formally?
2. > Is it a good way to analyze 1. by perturbation method (I think this should be a regular perturbation method)? (observe the sign of the leading order term of the solution obtained from perturbation method?) and how could I proceed it for the coupling term?

Note: It is simple to check that if you just use the linearization method to find the Jacobian matrix (w.r.t the point $(0,0)$), the ROA will be the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is not correct.

Comment: I think geometry and few basic facts for dynamical systems on the plane would be enough here. When you are speaking about basins of attraction for planar systems a boundary of such basins usually consists of unstable limit cycles or union of stable separatrices of saddles with equilibria. When $\epsilon = 0$ the boundary of attraction region consists of saddle equilibria at $(1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, $(-1, 0)$, $(0, -1)$, their stable separatrices and unstable nodes at  $(1, 1)$, $(-1, 1)$, $(-1, -1)$, $(1, -1)$. If you are interested in small values of $\epsilon$, all you have to do is to check ...

Comment: ... how saddles move when $\epsilon$ changes and in what direction their stable eigenspace rotates. This would give you an explanation why ROA is tilted in one way or another. (Also, I disagree with the red curve as a boundary of ROA)

Comment: @Evgeny The red curve is the one approximated by some numerical methods; therefore it is not a perfect square.

Comment: Interesting question. How did you obtain the three curves? I‘am only familiar with approximation via Lyapunov functions, however this way is mostly rather conservative...